# The negation of $(\forall \varepsilon >0) (\exists N\in \mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})$ if $ n\geq N,$ then $ |a_{n}-a|<\varepsilon $

Tags: logic

I am trying to negate the following expression:

$(\forall \varepsilon >0) (\exists N\in \mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})$: if $n\geq N, $ then $ |a_{n}-a|<\varepsilon $.

My negation is the following:

$(\forall \varepsilon >0) (\forall N\in \mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})$: if $n\geq N,$ then $ |a_{n}-a|\geq  \varepsilon $

Is it correct?

Thanks

Comment: Try to find it logically. What is the opposite of "for all $\epsilon>0$ something happens"? It must be "there exists some $\epsilon>0$ for which it doesn't happen". And continue this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

When you push in the negation past the quantifiers, every $\exists$ becomes a $\forall$, and vice versa.

Also, the negation of $P \to Q$ is $P \land \neg Q$

With that, try again.

Comment: Is it now correct? 
$(\exists \varepsilon >0) (\forall N\in \mathbb{N})(\exists n\in\mathbb{N})$: if $n<  N, $ then $ |a_{n}-a|\geq \varepsilon $.

Comment: $n\geq N$ and $ |a_{n}-a|\geq  \varepsilon $ like this?

Comment: @MartinN. Yes on that last part

Answer (score 1):

There exists an $\epsilon >0$, and for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n \ge N$ implies

$|a_n-a| \ge \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Following Bram's recipe:

$$\exists \varepsilon>0: \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: (n > N) \land |a_n -a | \ge \varepsilon$$

of in words: there is some distance $\varepsilon$ such that infinitely many terms in the sequence have distance at least $\varepsilon$ from $a$.